# Sort HTML attributes without JavaScript

Tags: html, css, sorting, time, css-selectors

I'm supposed to sort paragraphs by `<time>` without using JavaScript. I'm currently searching for CSS functions to help me solve this issue. I appreciate it if you could help me solve this issue. I found this codepen code [https://codepen.io/julieblanc/pen/YzPrxva] but I'm really confused. Thank you in advance.

```html
 <section class="timeline">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <h2 class='section-headline'>The Timeline</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
                    <!--Item 1-->
                    <div class="timeline-item timeline-1">
                     
                        <div class="timeline-item-content">
                            <h3>1x6g</h3>
                            <time>17 August 1958</time>
                            <p>The invention discloses a method and a system for recognizing spam texts, which comprises the following steps: extracting features of spam samples, confirming spam features from all the features of the spam samples according to the probability of the spam texts attribute to the texts including the features, endowing a spam weight for each spam feature and form</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--Item 2-->
                    <div class="timeline-item timeline-2">
                       
                        <div class="timeline-item-content">
                            <h3>hghfs</h3>
                            <time>23 September 1958</time>
                            <p>The invention discloses a method and a system for recognizing spam texts, which comprises the following steps: extracting features of spam samples, confirming spam features from all the features of the spam samples according to the probability of the spam texts attribute to the texts including the features, endowing a spam weight for each spam feature and form</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--Item 3-->
                    <div class="timeline-item timeline-3">
                       
                        <div class="timeline-item-content">
                            <h3>jgfsfs 11</h3>
                            <time>16 July 1969</time>
                            <p>The invention discloses a method and a system for recognizing spam texts, which comprises the following steps: extracting features of spam samples, confirming spam features from all the features of the spam samples according to the probability of the spam texts attribute to the texts including the features, endowing a spam weight for each spam feature and form</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--End of Class Col12-lg-6-->
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
                    <!--Item 4-->
                    <div class="timeline-item timeline-4">
                     
                        <div class="timeline-item-content">
                            <h3>ldrth4</h3>
                            <time>9 August 1976</time>
                            <p>The invention discloses a method and a system for recognizing spam texts, which comprises the following steps: extracting features of spam samples, confirming spam features from all the features of the spam samples according to the probability of the spam texts attribute to the texts including the features, endowing a spam weight for each spam feature and form</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--Item 5-->
                    <div class="timeline-item timeline-5">
                      
                        <div class="timeline-item-content">
                            <h3>oprhe</h3>
                            <time>24 January 1990</time>
                            <p>The invention discloses a method and a system for recognizing spam texts, which comprises the following steps: extracting features of spam samples, confirming spam features from all the features of the spam samples according to the probability of the spam texts attribute to the texts including the features, endowing a spam weight for each spam feature and form</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--Item 6-->
                    <div class="timeline-item timeline-6">
                        
                        <div class="timeline-item-content">
                            <h3>1us5</h3>
                            <time>Spring 2010</time>
                            <p>The invention discloses a method and a system for recognizing spam texts, which comprises the following steps: extracting features of spam samples, confirming spam features from all the features of the spam samples according to the probability of the spam texts attribute to the texts including the features, endowing a spam weight for each spam feature and form</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: The codepen you found is more of a tech demo than something a sane person would actually do on a website that is supposed to do more than showing off CSS skills. Also, it does not sort anything, only apply filters. Unless there is a *very* good reason (that means: more than *"I'm supposed to..."*) to not use JavaScript, use JavaScript.

Comment: I'm applying for a job and this is the only task I couldn't solve. I need hints, insights, recommendations .. anything!

Comment: You could try playing with `display: flex` and then overwrite the [`order` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items#the_order_property) depending on certain conditions, much like the Codepen demo switches between `display: none` and `display: block` depending on certain conditions. It would give the _appearance_ of "sorting by date", but of course it would all be preconfigured, hard-coded values in the CSS.

Comment: Excellent Idea, it might work. Thanks!